# Defining an "arg max" like function over finite sets, and proving some of its properties, and avoiding a detour via lists

Tags: list, function, set, fold, isabelle

I'm working with a custom implementation of vectors as functions whose domain is a finite "index set" of natural numbers, and whose image is of some type on which one can define a maximum, usually `real`.  E.g. I could have a two-dimensional vector `v` with `v 1 = 2.7` and `v 3 = 4.2`.

On such vectors I'd like to define an "arg max" like operator, which tells me the index of the maximum component, `3` in the example of `v` above.  I'm saying "the" index because the "arg max" like operator will additionally accept a tie-breaking function to be applied to components with values.  (The background is [bids in auctions](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/research/projects/formare/code/auction-theory/).)

I know that `Max` on finite sets is defined using `fold1` (of which I do not yet understand how it works).  I tried this, which was accepted in itself, but then didn't work for the other things I wanted to do:

```
fun arg_max_tb :: "index_set ⇒ tie_breaker ⇒ (real vector) ⇒ nat"
where "arg_max_tb N t v = fold1
  (λ x y . if (v x > v y) then x      (* component values differ *)
   else if (v x = v y ∧ t x y) then x (* tie-breaking needed *)
   else y) N"
```

Note that furthermore I would like to *prove* certain properties of my "arg max" like operator, which will likely require induction.  I know that there is the rule `finite_ne_induct` for induction over finite sets.  OK, but I would also like to be able to define my operator in such a way that it can be evaluated (e.g. when trying with concrete finite sets), but evaluating

```
value "arg_max_tb {1::nat} (op >) (nth [27::real, 42])"
```

with expected return value `1` gives me the following error:

```
Wellsortedness error
(in code equation arg_max_tb ?n ?t ?v \equiv
                  fold1 (\lambda x y. if ord_real_inst.less_real (?v y) (?v x) then ...) ?n):
Type nat not of sort enum
 No type arity nat :: enum
```

Therefore I resorted to converting my finite sets to lists.  On lists I have been able to define the operator, and to prove some of its properties (can share the code if it's of interest) by induction using `list_nonempty_induct`.

The working list-based definition looks as follows:

```
fun arg_max_l_tb :: "(nat list) ⇒ tie_breaker ⇒ (real vector) ⇒ nat"
where "arg_max_l_tb [] t v = 0"
      (* in practice we will only call the function
         with lists of at least one element *)
    | "arg_max_l_tb [x] t v = x"
    | "arg_max_l_tb (x # xs) t v =
      (let y = arg_max_l_tb xs t v in
        if (v x > v y) then x              (* component values differ *)
        else if (v x = v y ∧ t x y) then x (* tie-breaking needed *)
        else y)"

fun arg_max_tb :: "index_set ⇒ tie_breaker ⇒ (real vector) ⇒ nat"
where "arg_max_tb N t v = arg_max_l_tb (sorted_list_of_set N) t v"
```

I didn't succeed to directly define a function over the constructors of a finite set.  The following doesn't work:

```
fun arg_max_tb :: "index_set ⇒ tie_breaker ⇒ (real vector) ⇒ participant"
where "arg_max_tb {} t b = 0"
    | "arg_max_tb {x} t b = x"
    | "arg_max_tb (insert x S) t b =
      (let y = arg_max_tb S t b in
        if (b x > b y) then x
        else if (b x = b y ∧ t x y) then x
        else y)"
```

It gives me the error message

```
Malformed definition:
Non-constructor pattern not allowed in sequential mode.
⋀t b. arg_max_tb {} t b = 0
```

Could this be because the list constructors are defined as a `datatype`, whereas finite sets are merely defined as an `inductive` scheme?

Whatever – do you know of a way of defining this function over finite sets?  Either by writing it down directly, or by some fold-like utility function?

Comment: In its full generality, the function you give as argument to fold1 is not commutative. For this you need additional properties, namely `t` must be a linear order (on `N`). You don't need this with `sorted_list_of_set`, because this uses (implicitly) the linear order on `a` for a final disambiguation (which you could also do with `fold1`, if you wanted).

Comment: Yes, `fun` only works for datatypes. `function` can in theory also work with non-constructor patterns, however, you will need to prove that this definition is consistent, as "{}" and "insert" are not free (i.e. `insert 1 (insert 2 {})` and `insert 2 (insert 1 {})` describe the same set, despite being different terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question really consists of multiple questions.

## Defining a function on finite sets

### fold / foldl1

The usual recursion combinator is `Finite_Set.fold` (or `fold1`). However, to be able to prove anything `fold f z S`, the result must be independent of the order `f` is applied to the elements of `S`.

If `f` is associative and commutative, you can use  `Finite_Set.ab_semigroup_mult.fold1_insert`  and `Finite_Set.fold1_singleton` to get simp rules for `fold1 f S` and you should be able to use `finite_ne_induct` as your induction rule.

Note that the function (I'll call it `f`) you give to fold1 is only commutative if `t` is a linear order:

```
fun arg_max_tb :: "index_set ⇒ tie_breaker ⇒ (real vector) ⇒ nat"
where "arg_max_tb N t v = fold1
  (λ x y . if (v x > v y) then x      (* component values differ *)
   else if (v x = v y ∧ t x y) then x (* tie-breaking needed *)
   else y) N"
```

This is not covered by the existing lemmas on fold1, so you either need to prove a generalized variant of `Finite_Set.ab_semigroup_mult.fold1_insert` or insert an additional tie-breaker, e.g.

```
   else if (v x = v y ∧ ~t x y ∧ ~t y x ∧ x < y) then x
```

If `t` is a linear order, you will be able to remove this additional tie-breaker from the simp rules. Note that this additional tie-breaker is basically what you get from using `sorted_list_of_set`.

### THE / SOME

Your `arg_max_tb` selects one element of a list with certain properties. This can also be defined directly with the constructs `THE x. P x` or `SOME x. P x` (choice operators). The former selects the unique element satisfying the property P (if no unique element exists, the result is undefined), the latter selects some element satisfying the property P (if no such element exists, the result is undefined). Both work for infinite lists, too.

These are often preferable if you don't need executable code.

## Getting an executable function

Functions defined by recursion (i.e. `primrec`, `fun` or `function`) are executable by default (if all functions used in their definition are executable, too). `THE` and `SOME` can in general only be executed for enumerable domains (this is the error message you got from `value` -- `nat` is not enumerable, as it is not finite).

However, you can always give an alternative definition of your function to the code generator. See the *Tutorial on Function Definitions*, in particular the section about refinement.

If you prefer the formulation with choice operators for proving, but also like your function to be executable, the easiest way might to prove that the definitions of `arg_max_tb` via choice and `sorted_list_of_set` are equivalent. Then you can use the `[code_unfold]` predicate to replace the definition by choice with the (executable) definition by `sorted_list_of_set`

Comment: Thanks!  I'll probably continue pragmatically, as follows: generate executable code from the list-based `fun`, also use the list-based `fun` on the “theoretical” side of my work, but once proving properties of that function starts to hurt, I will do what you suggested in the section “Getting an executable function”.

Comment: A rejected edit commented on my use of "undefined", suggesting "arbitrary" instead: Isabelle/HOL is a logic of total functions, so  every type correct expression has a value, even those I called "undefined". The correct word would probably have been "underspecified" -- we cannot prove anything about such a value, which does not hold for all values of its type. The word "undefined" comes from the Isabelle constant `undefined` which is just a constant of type `'a` without any definition -- it behaves similar to `THE x. False)`.

Answer (score 4):

Folding over a finite set requires that the result is independent of the order in which the elements of the set are visited, because sets are unordered. Most lemmas about `fold1 f` therefore assume that the folding operation `f` is left-commutative, i.e., `f a (f b x) = f b (f a x)` for all `a`, `b`, `x`.

The function that you supply to `fold1` in your first definition does not satisfy this because the tie-breaking function is an arbitrary predicate. For example, take the tie-breaking function `%v v'. True`. Hence, if you want to stick to this definition, you will have to find sufficient conditions on the tie-breaking first and thread this assumption through all your lemmata.

Your working solution based on a sorted list of the elements avoids this commutatitivity problem. Your last suggestion with pattern matching on `{}`, `{x}` and `insert x S` does not work for two reasons. First, `fun` can only pattern-match on datatype constructors, so you would have to use `function` instead; this explains the error message. But then, you also have to prove the equations do not overlap and you will therefore run into the same problem with commutativity again. Additionally, you will not be able to prove termination because `S` might be infinite.

The well-sortedness error for code generation comes from the setup for `fold1`. `fold1 f A` is defined as `THE x. fold1Set f A x` where `fold1Set f A x` holds iff `x` is the result of folding `f` over `A` in some order of the elements. To check that all the results are the same, the generated code naively tests for all possible values of `x` whether `fold1Set f A x` holds. If it indeed finds just one such value, then it returns that value. Otherwise, it raises an exception. In your case, `x` is an index, i.e., of type `nat` which infinitely many values inhabit. Hence, exhaustive testing is not possible. Technically, this translates as `nat` not being an instance of the type class `enum`.

Normally, you derive specialised code equations for everything that you define in terms of `fold1`. See the code generator tutorial on program refinement.

Comment: Thanks, Andreas, while I prefer Lars' approach for my further work, I found your explanation quite instructive too :-)